# How can I discover what app is flashing (open and closes really fast)?

Tags: windows

I'm using windows 10 and have an app that opens and closes a window really fast. I'm unable to see much else than that and this occurs around 4 to 5 times per hour so it's not overly annoying.

How can I discover witch app is doing it and how can I prevent this?

Comment: procmon logs every action that happens including starting and stopping of programs. You can use it to monitor the system. Do note that it logs so much, you really do have to shift through a lot of lines if you don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: Do  you have enough time to take a screenshot or record a screen video?

Comment: @Biswa A screenshot no because I don't know when it's going to happen and I'm not that fast :(. But the video is great idea I will give it a try.

Comment: @LPChip I didn't knew about that program I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Use AutoRuns and configure an absolute minimum boot configuration.  The goal is to have your system boot but not have the behavior happen.  Enable each entry one by one until the behavior returns.

Comment: Same here! Have you came to a solution?

Comment: It may be related to OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration bug task: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/officebackgroundtaskhandlerregistration-flashes-a/2600497e-78e4-41a1-9040-461cd2c3ea13